# Can't resolve module while doing ES6 import

Tags: reactjs, import, es6-modules

I am trying to import bignumber.js package into my project, but I keep failing to do so. Whenever I use statement

```
import {BigNumber} from 'bignumber';
```

or

```
import BigNumber from 'bignumber';
```

which are the statements taken directly from bignumber.js documentation, the error I am getting is:

```
./src/Component.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bignumber' in 
'PROJECT_DIR\src'
```

In ***PROJECT_DIR\node_modules*** bignumber is indeed installed and I am unable to grasp what the problem is exactly.
I would be grateful for any insight towards this problem.
Cheers!

Comment: I think you need to change your import to `import {BigNumber} from 'big-number';`

Comment: Tried both bold importing and destructuring importing, none of those helps.

Comment: can you link the big number module you are trying to use. is it this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number because this one has a - in it. you could also try import * as bigNumber from 'bignumber'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import **bignumber.js** package use:
`import { BigNumber } from "bignumber.js"`

You can view an example here: [codesandbox-bignumber](https://codesandbox.io/s/641x2r9zwn)
I included also **big-number** module/example for the case that you want to use this module.

Comment: Yeah, ES6 imports need the full filename IIRC.